# Perform method using storyboard segue

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a method on my 2nd View Controller that sets a label's text from a value from the 1st View Controller. How can I call the method on prepareForSegue? I have set my method on the 2nd VC as `-(void)setName:(NSString *)name;` Then I call it in the prepareForSegue as `[secondVC setName:@"Steve Jobs"];` but the label doesn't seem to change its text, though I can see the value when I NSLog the name variable.

Comment: so, `secondVC` is a `UILabel` ?

Comment: secondVC contains a method that sets the name for the UILabel, assuming inside said method is something along the lines of myLabel.text = name;

Comment: Make sure you are not setting the label title in viewDidAppear as this may override the value you pass in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the text on a label that hasn't been loaded yet because `prepareForSeque` happens before `viewDidLoad`.

One solution is to set the text on a property of the second VC in `prepareForSegue` and then configure the label with that text in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that prepareForSegue  comes before viewDidLoad. That is why it is not setting the label's text. Overlooked this detail since I've only started using storyboards now.